# Calculate if polygon is big enough to be visible on gmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google map with a few polygons displayed. Some of them are very small and are not visible at certain zoom level.

I was thinking of putting an icon or a tooltip over polygons that were too small to be visible, with a click handler that would zoom in to a level where the polygon would become visible. I would put this check inside the "zoom_changed" map handler.

My maths are not strong enough to figure out the right algorithm to see the relation between the area of my polygons and the zoom level. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LatLngBounds` to store your polygons' Lats and lngs. Then you can use `map.setCenter()` and `map.fitBounds()`.

Sample code:

```
 var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords.length; i++) {
        latlngbounds.extend(triangleCoords[i]);
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < testCoords.length; i++) {
        latlngbounds.extend(testCoords[i]);
   }


    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

You can see the complete implementation in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgmp1v0x/ Or this one with different polygon: http://jsfiddle.net/dgmp1v0x/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think I didn't phrase my question correctly. The zooming part is not what is giving me problems, it's more about the visibility of polygons in relation to the zoom level of the map (a really small polygon won't be visible until you zoom in enough).

Comment: You can use `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(yourPolygon.getPath())` to calculate the areas of your polygons. In certain zoom level, you can determine which small areas need to place a marker or info window.

Comment: thanks ztan, I did find this one out. As stated by the last paragraph of my question, I'm trying to find the right maths between a polygon area and a zoom level (and maybe even screen dpi ?) to figure out if a polygon is visible at a certain level.